# Website Connection TImeout AWS EC2, crashes after uploading multiple images

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a proyect developed in the laravel framework which works fine, when the user uploads various images in the project it starts to slow down and the website returns the following error:

> connection timeout or server response: 0.

This error only happens **after uploading 20 or 30 images**. The request is per image, the request is sent, the image is uploaded and then the next request is sent to the server to upload the next image. I believe the server is using all the resources and that is why after a while the website starts to crash down and slow down. I am using an `AWS EC2` instance based on Linux, here  is a screenshot of the specifications. If I need to change the `EC2` instance to a bigger one which one do you recommend to meet this requirements?
**Average Size of image:7MB** . I am using `AWS S3` to store the images and dropzone.js to attach the images. **The configuration is made to sent one image by one image.**

> Currently selected: t2.micro (Variable ECUs, 1 vCPUs, 2.5 GHz, Intel
>   Xeon Family, 1 GiB memory, EBS only)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e31Mf.png)

Comment: Have sou checked the instance cpu/mem usage in the ec2 console? Could also connect to the console and run top to check this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the CPU credit balance for your t2.micro instance(If it is using all the compute then the credit balance should be 0). Try using a bigger EC2 instance, maybe m5.large which will provide higher bandwidth and compute. You should also check the web proxy parameters(Apache or Nginx or any other webserver which you must have used) with respect to the size of images that you are processing.